# javascript: open file from byte array returned by json

Tags: javascript, java, json

In javasript, I have a byte array and want to transform it back to the original fileType and open it. I have tried both with image/png and application/pdf but the result is the same. The file is damaged and can not be opened. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Server side, my java code is like this:

```
...
File downloadFile = myService.retriveMyFile(input);
byte[] fileInBytes = new byte[(int)downloadFile.length()];
InputStream inputStream = null;
try {        
   inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile);            
   inputStream.read(fileInBytes);            
} finally {
   inputStream.close();
}
String json = new Gson().toJson(fileInBytes);
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

In javascript I try to open the file like this

```
...
var a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = "display: none";
var fileName = "test.png";
xhr.onload = function () {
   if (xhr.status === 200) {
   var jsonResponse = xhr.response;
   var json = JSON.stringify(jsonResponse),
   blob = new Blob([json], {type: "image/png"}),
   url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   a.href = url;
   a.download = fileName;
   a.click();
   window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something going wrong when you try to send the bytes as JSON.
It is easier to directly send the bytes:

**On the server:**

Open an InputStream for `downloadFile` and copy its content to `response.getOutputStream()` .

**On the client:**

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = "display: none";
var fileName = "test.png";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open( "GET", <theurl>, true);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function() {
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);  
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: document.body.appendChild(url);  //required in FF, optional for Chrome

otherwise it wont work on FF